# Why I get OutOfMemory exception when trying create a decoder

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, directx, h.264

I'm trying to get ID3D11VideoDecoder Decoder with h264 decoder profile but catching exception on Windows Phone 8. 
Using this code:

```
DX::ThrowIfFailed(device.Get()->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11VideoDevice), (void**)&videoDevice));
GUID guid = {0x1b81be68, 0xa0c7,0x11d3,{0xb9,0x84,0x00,0xc0,0x4f,0x2e,0x73,0xc5}};

D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_DESC *desc = new D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_DESC();
desc->Guid = guid;
desc->OutputFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_420_OPAQUE;
desc->SampleHeight = 480;
desc->SampleWidth = 800;

D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG *conf = new D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG();
ID3D11VideoDecoder *decoder;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(videoDevice.Get()->CreateVideoDecoder(desc, conf, &decoder));
```

PS. I tried SharpDX for this and got the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found solution.

for H264 decoder ConfigBitstreamRaw field must be "2". Not "1", not "0". Only "2". Like this

```
    VideoDecoderDescription decoderDescription = new VideoDecoderDescription();
    decoderDescription.OutputFormat = Format.Opaque420;
    decoderDescription.SampleHeight = 480;
    decoderDescription.SampleWidth = 800;
    decoderDescription.Guid = _formatGuid;

    VideoDecoderConfig config = new VideoDecoderConfig();
    config.ConfigMinRenderTargetBuffCount = 1;
    config.ConfigBitstreamRaw = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't pass in a valid D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG variable. you just define a pointer of struct D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG and didn't set the values of it before calling function CreateVideoDecoder.

```
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG *conf = new D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG();
DX::ThrowIfFailed(videoDevice.Get()->CreateVideoDecoder(desc, conf, &decoder));
```

You can try it as below.

```
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_CONFIG conf
ZeroMemory(&conf, sizeof(conf));
conf.guidConfigBitstreamEncryption = xxx;
...
conf.ConfigDecoderSpecific = xxx;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(videoDevice.Get()->CreateVideoDecoder(desc, conf, &decoder));
```

Comment: I tried it. The same problem. 

I don't why, but if I will try using other Decoder Profile (for example VC1 or MPEG2) - It will success. Problem only when I trying with h264 ...